# How to remove Page URL from routing path in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, web, razor, razor-pages

I have an `Image` folder with some files, and a table with the path of this images. When trying to list the images like this:

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Product.Image)
    {   
            <img src="@image.Path" height="100" />
    }
```

ASP.NET references `@image.Path` with the Page route(print from Google Dev Tools):

[image]

It seems to be really simple to solve this problem, but I've got no clue how to do.

I just need to remove the `Products/` part o f the URL and my problem is solved. I don't understand why Razor references `@image.Path` in this context with the name of the `Controller`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somthing like this

```
@foreach (var image in Model.Product.Image)
{   
   var iPhotoUrl = "/Image/" + (image.Path ?? "noimage.png");      
   <img src="@iPhotoUrl" height="100" />
}
```

Also share the value return on @image.Path

Answer (score 0):

For my delight, just putting an `~/` before the `@image.Path`(I think it "hardcoded" the source) solved the problem.

The code:

`<img src="~/@image.Path" height="100" />`